# clojure list? and macros

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to understand how clojure macros apply to lists. I'm confused by the following:

```
(defmacro islist [f] (list? f))
(islist (1 2)) ; true
(islist '(1 2)) ; false
(islist (quote (1 2))) ; true
```

Is this expected? I've noticed that lists I pass to to macros return false when evaluated with `list?` inside the macro. That is, the second example is particularly confusing.

Comment: You sure you don't want this? (defmacro islist[f] `(list? ~f))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the macro `'(1 2)` is of type `clojure.lang.Cons` (you can check this by changing `list?` to `type`). `list?` returns true iff the operand is of type `clojure.lang.IPersistentList`.

```
user=> (isa? clojure.lang.Cons clojure.lang.IPersistentList)
false
```

The reason `clojure.lang.Cons` appears is because the reader constructs a cons cell when expanding `'(1 2)` to `(quote (1 2))`, whereas it doesn't when you spell out `quote` directly as `(quote (1 2))`.

You probably want to use `seq?` instead of `list?`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if this was a conscious design choice? I was surprised when https://gist.github.com/karansag/2b907d0d9c570552d33f worked, so I asked this question.